# Xampp sendmail gmail windows 10

Tags: php, xampp, sendmail

I'm trying to configure XAMPP(v. 5.6.15) with sendmail to work with my Gmail account to send messages from localhost. I know that's an old issue, but previous answers doesn't seem to work in my case.
In php.ini I have:

```
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=465
sendmail_from = email@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
mail.add_x_header=Off
```

and in sendmail.ini:

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=465
smtp_ssl=ssl
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=smtp.gmail.com
auth_password=private-pass
pop3_server=
pop3_username=
pop3_password=
force_sender=thearturoo87@gmail.com
force_recipient=
hostname=smtp.gmail.com
```

in auth_password field I'm using application specific password generated in my Gmail account. Currently I'm working on Windows 10 and I have configured sendmail.exe to run as administrator.
When I run my PHP script:

```
<?php
require_once("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->SetFrom('email@gmail.com', 'First Last');
$mail->AddAddress("email@gmail.com", "John Doe");
$mail->Subject = "PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), basic";
$mail->AltBody = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
$mail->MsgHTML("test message");
if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
```

I notice that sendmail.exe window appears and the script won't complete until I close this window, when I do then I see "Message sent!" message but I don't receive anything on my Gmail account.
Do you have any suggestions on how can I resolve this ?
Regards